# TinyMCE paste from excel

Tags: excel, format, tinymce

I have a problem with TinyMCE editor which I cannot resolve.

If I copy a table from Excel and paste it into the editor it loses the formatting. I have set up extended_valid_elements as follows...

*extended_valid_elements:"a[name|href|target|title|onclick],img[class|src|border=0|alt|title|hspace|vspace|width|height|align|onmouseover|onmouseout|name],table[style|class|border=2|width|cellspacing|cellpadding|bgcolor],colgroup,col[style|width],tbody,tr[style|class],td[style|class|colspan|rowspan|width|height|background|span|padding],hr[class|width|size|noshade],font[face|size|color|style],span[class|align|style|font-family|color]"*

The HTML that is saved into the MySQL field is as follows

From Excel ...

```
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 242pt;" border="2" width="322">
<tbody>
<tr style="height: 14.25pt;">
<td style="height: 14.25pt; width: 105pt;" width="140">Test</td>
<td style="width: 104pt;" width="138"></td>
<td style="width: 33pt;" width="44">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

From Word ...

```
<table style="width: 242.0pt; border-collapse: collapse;" border="2" width="0">
<tbody>
<tr style="height: 14.25pt;">
<td style="width: 105.0pt; padding: 0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height: 14.25pt;" width="140">
<p style="margin-bottom: .0001pt; line-height: normal;"><span style="font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: 'Arial',sans-serif; color: black;">Test</span></p>
</td>
<td style="width: 104.0pt; padding: 0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height: 14.25pt;" width="139"></td>
<td style="width: 33.0pt; background: #92D050; padding: 0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; height: 14.25pt;" width="44">
<p style="margin-bottom: .0001pt; line-height: normal;"><span style="font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: 'Arial',sans-serif; color: black;">&nbsp;</span></p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

How can I make this work from excel without having to go through word first?

Answer (score 0):

It would appear I have to use power paste which is a paid-for option ... I have a call setup with their sales team to see how much it will cost! Fingers crossed.